# Is the convergence to the closure pointwise or uniform?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Let $\bar S$ be the closure of a set of functions, suppose $f$ is a function in $\bar S$. Then there exists a sequence of function converging to $f$ by definition of closure.

Is the convergence pointwise or uniform? Why?

I think it is uniform, but I am not sure why this is the case. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

Closure in what metric?  If it's the sup-norm, the convergence is uniform.    If it's some other metric, convergence is in the sense of that metric, and might not be uniform (or pointwise either, for that matter).  If it's a non-metrizable topology, there might not be such a sequence.

By the way, if $K$ is an uncountable compact metric space, there is no metric on $C(K)$ (the continuous functions on $K$) such that a sequence converges in this metric iff it converges pointwise.

Comment: In the sup norm. Why is the convergence uniform and not pointwise dear sir?

Comment: If $\| \cdot \|$ is the sup-norm, $\|f_n - f \| \le \epsilon$ means $|f_n(x) - f(x)| \le \epsilon$ for all $x$.  It's not "not pointwise", it's both pointwise and uniform.  Uniform implies pointwise.